# How to create a custom knob for iOS slider?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to subclass just the knob for iOS slider (if yes, how: can you point to a tutorial) or does one has to create the whole slider from scratch ?

Comment: Check out this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image

Comment: Thanks for the link didn't find it when searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apple's documentation for UISlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) indicates that the thumb is customizable. You need to set the currentThumbImage property and override `- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value`
in a UISlider subclass.