# Change UISlider background with code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a `UISlider` , and i want to change its look .
I dont want to change its image with my own, like this one 
[Change iPhone UISlider bar image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image)

but, to create an `elliptical UIView` of my own,in code, and set it instead of the current slider thin line, than instead of the moving circle button, create a `circle UIView` in code, and replace it also.

I know i can set their images ,

```
[self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchBlueBg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOffPlain.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but how do i set my own costume uiview ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a circular Slider,you can check it once: http://code4app.net/ios/EFCircularSlider/52a6bdd9cb7e84af088b5fa8