# How can i add marks on UISlider in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uislider

I want to add marks on UISlider using objective-c 
on specific point of UISilder.

Like this two dots/marks on slider

[image]

Comment: Just see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

- Download `JMMarkSlider` from below link.

  https://github.com/brightec/JMMarkSlider
- import `#import "JMMarkSlider.h"`

then use below code:

```
self.firstSlider.markColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
self.firstSlider.markPositions = @[@10,@20,@30,@40,@50,@60,@70,@80,@90,@100];
self.firstSlider.markWidth = 1.0;
self.firstSlider.selectedBarColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.firstSlider.unselectedBarColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

There are many customization options are also available.